# Android Composite ADB Interface Windows 8 driver for iRulu U2?

Tags: adb, usb-drivers

I downloaded and [installed](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7) via Android SDK Manager (rev 24.2) the latest [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) (rev 11).

`adb devices` works well with my `Nexus S G4` (Android 4.1.2) and is able to list it without any problem.

`adb devices` cannot detect my `iRulu U2` (Android 4.4.4).

On my PC's Device Manager it shows up as `MT65xx Android Phone`:

[image]

iRulu's website is of no help: 
The list on http://www.irulu.com/DownLoad/driver is cryptic and when I finally guessed a search term *"driver"*, it found one item:

`MTKDriver_Auto_Installer_EXE_v1.1236.00`

I downloaded it but upon attempt to install it, Device Manager's wizard complains that it is unsigned.

Any idea where I can find a USB driver that works with the `iRulu U2`?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

After much search I found [this post](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH) by Koushik Dutta who kindly shared his own developed `Universal ADB Driver`.

In there I found the installer ([UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi)) and the source code for it.

After running it, my iRulu U2 is now recognized by Device Manager as `HTC Android Interface`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment (need 50 points) so I am posting this as an answer complementing the OP:

[These specifications](http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/776d3725) state that the iRulu U2's SoC (system on chip) is `MediaTek MT6582V/X` and its CPU is ARM Cortex-A7, 1300 MHz (4 Cores).

This phone looks like a clone of "something more supported" (LG G3?), so to find a compatible driver, perhaps one has to look for a well known brand phone with specs similar to this:

- **Dimensions**: 69.2 x 135.2 x 8.5 mm
- **Weight**: 143 g
- **SoC**: MediaTek MT6582V/X
- **CPU**: ARM Cortex-A7, 1300 MHz, Cores: 4
- **GPU**: ARM Mali-400 MP2, 500 MHz, Cores: 2
- **RAM**: 1 GB, 533 MHz
- **Storage**: 8 GB
- **Memory cards**: microSD, microSDHC
- **Display**: 5 in, IPS, 540 x 960 pixels, 24 bit
- **Battery**: 2000 mAh, Li-Ion
- **OS**: Android 4.4.2 KitKat
- **Camera**: 4128 x 3096 pixels, 1920 x 1080 pixels, 30 fps
- **SIM card**: Mini-SIM, Micro-SIM
- **Wi-Fi**: b, g, n, Wi-Fi Hotspot
- **USB**: 2.0, Micro USB
- **Bluetooth**: 4.0
- **Positioning**: GPS, A-GPS

More specifically, look at this Wikipedia list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_using_Mediatek_SoCs#MT6582

And even more specific to the MediaTek MT6582**V/X**:

e.g. Gionee Ctrl V5, Gionee Pioneer P4, Intex Aqua Life, Obi Boa S503, Fly Evo Energy 4. All "no name" brands, just like the iRulu U2.